# Avoid bottom bar hide jump when seguing ios

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, autolayout

How can I fix this jump that occurs around 1.5 seconds in when the bottom bar disappears on push? The view extends to the full height of the screen due to autolayout. I want it to be full height even if the bottom bar is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Immediately before segueing, I force it hidden.

```
    if (self.tabBarController) {
        self.tabBarController!.tabBar.hidden = true;
    }
```